# Not getting white boot screen background on white iPad/iPhone (iOS 7)?

Tags: ios

Is this a bug I need to report or is this normal or what? On both my white iPad 2 and my white iPhone 4S running iOS 7, I thought the boot screen was supposed to be white/gray with a dark Apple logo, but I'm getting the black screen with the white logo. But since it's the same on both devices maybe I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The color-specifc boot screens are only available on the iPhone 5 and later.

On these devices, the boot screen will match the colour of the front panel e.g. a white iPhone 5 will display a white screen with a black Apple logo.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS boot screen prior to iOS 6 has always been a black screen with a white(-ish plus silver/gray details) Apple logo.

Comment: Previously it has, but white iPhone 5(s) on iOS 7 get treated to a white boot screen with a flat Apple logo.

Comment: I'm shocked I've never seen this before. Then again how often do you see someone else's phone boot?